# checkbox with ng-change is not working with datatable and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, datatable

my code is as below,

```
vm.dtColumns.push(DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('<input name="select_all" value="1" id="example-select-all" type="checkbox" ng-change="checkedAll()" />').renderWith(actionHtml).withOption('orderable', false));
```

my function is as below,

```
$scope.checkedAll = function () {
           alert(); 
        }
```

but on checkbox change this function is not working

Please help me to resolve above

Answer (score 0):

Might be due to the fact that you don't have an `ng-model` on that input.

[The documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) states that `ng-model` has to be present for the `ng-change` to work.

> The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input value causes a new value to be committed to the model.
>
> ...
>
> Note, this directive requires ngModel to be present.

Comment: I have also added ng-model too,but still not working

Comment: My next guess would be that Angular might've not compiled that code and therefore ng-change and ng-model won't work. Could you please try to provide a JSFiddle or something?